missing system dependencies for ns3
I have been setting up ns-3-allinone on my WSL Python virtual environment using the in-built 'bake' tool. However during the setup, after running ./bake.py download or ./bake.py show the following system dependencies are said to be missing from my virtual environment:
gi-cairo
pygobject
pygraphviz
This is despite the fact I've installed these packages through both pip install and sudo apt install commands. Running pip list on the virtual environment shows these system-dependencies as present, yet still the bake command shows them as missing. Any suggestions on what to do?
